# Ubuntu installation shows used space as free

Tags: partitioning, 13.10, windows-8

I wanted to dual boot ubuntu and windows 8. I followed instruction found in Internet to create unallocated space from `Disk Management` in windows 8. But, I cannot see that space in my ubuntu installation window. Please look at the screenshot below:

[image]

Kindly suggest how can I manage to dual boot windows 8 and ubuntu in this case

Answer (score 0):

You've got a damaged partition table or leftover RAID data. [This page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/index.html) covers the issue in detail. Chances are you can fix it by running [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) on the disk, but the details depend on the exact cause.